# not able to run modified js code in chrome dev tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome-devtools

I am not able to run the modified code, after modification still chrome is debugging older code. I can see the green color on the web page which denotes that its pointing to the local file saved in my system. But still not able to run the modified code. I am able to do so by using console to modify the js files.
I am really stuck for 3 days and now i am pretty confused whats going on. I searched on google but it seems not working.

Comment: Any clairvoyant developers around here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below steps-
• Clear the browser cache.
• In case you are using Visual Studio, clean and the rebuild the solution. Or do the equivalent if you are using any other IDE.